# Nginx- redirect all subdomain traffic to https subdomain

Tags: nginx, ssl, website

What I'm trying to do is setup an 'unknown domain' page, however I'm trying to get http traffic to redirect to SSL traffic.
This is my server block:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri$is_args$args;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/mykey.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/mykey.key;
    root /home/unknown/;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name *.jamesj.me;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    error_page 401 /index.html;
    error_page 403 /index.html;
    error_page 404 /index.html;
    error_page 500 /index.html;
    error_page 501 /index.html;
    error_page 502 /index.html;
    error_page 503 /index.html;
}
```

Yet when I then go to http://sdfsf.jamesj.me/ it redirects me to https://_ .-.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server_name of _ isn't really recommended anymore in nginx. You are better off using something like

```
server_name *.domain.com;
```

Then $host should work

Comment: That still redirects me to https://_